# Service Reference adding getting certificate error

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, certificate

I am trying to add a service reference ie,[https://localhost/sd.Svc_Https/DesktopWSImpl.svc]

and i am getting the certificate Alert Message box like below:-

[image]

if i click on yes another error message box appears like below:-
[image]

and if i tried to access the same url in webbrowser then i am getting an error like :-
[image]

if i click on Continue then the below popup window will open asking to install:-
[image]

Can anyone help how to solve this issue and add the service reference?

Comment: What happens when you click **Continue to this website (not recommended)**?

Comment: @Halvard: if i click on continue to this website a popup window will appear for asking to confirm certificate.Once i click ok then only i can able to get accessing my webservices.

Comment: I don't know about the certificates, but the message about an error downloading metadata is often caused by errors in web.config of the service you are trying to connect to.  Do you control the web.config?  If so, check it properly.  Does it have a mex endpoint?  Full address in your endpoint contract?

Comment: @Halvard the message error got fixed by changing the ip address to webserver address.But again if i tried to update the service reference the error of downloading is coming which is mentioned in the image 2.

Comment: Could you post the vital parts of the web.config?

Comment: @Halvard:today only i could able to do a fix for the above, currently we are ignoring this error.